# After importing project in android studio there are some errors in XML file like URI is unrecognized

Tags: xml, file, element

I imported the project in android studio then in the XML file there are multiple errors of URI that is URI is unrecognized and XML file is not able to understand the android resources and its elements as well like textView and like wise.

[image: Android studio window showing XML style markup]

here is my XML file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/tan_background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.miwok.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numbers"
        style="@style/CategoryStyle"
        android:background="@color/category_numbers"
        android:text="@string/category_numbers" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/family"
        style="@style/CategoryStyle"
        android:background="@color/category_family"
        android:text="@string/category_family" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/colors"
        style="@style/CategoryStyle"
        android:background="@color/category_colors"
        android:text="@string/category_colors" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phrases"
        style="@style/CategoryStyle"
        android:background="@color/category_phrases"
        android:text="@string/category_phrases" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my string.xml file:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Title for the application. [CHAR LIMIT=12] -->
    <string name="app_name">Miwok</string>

    <!-- Category name for phrases [CHAR LIMIT=20] -->
    <string name="category_phrases">Phrases</string>

    <!-- Category name for the vocabulary words for colors [CHAR LIMIT=20] -->
    <string name="category_colors">Colors</string>

    <!-- Category name for the vocabulary words for numbers [CHAR LIMIT=20] -->
    <string name="category_numbers">Numbers</string>

    <!-- Category name for the vocabulary words for family members [CHAR LIMIT=20] -->
    <string name="category_family">Family Members</string>
</resources>
```

sync project with gradle files:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MpY1.png)

Comment: Post code as **text**

Comment: You xml contains special characters.  It looks like variable substitution was not done replace varaiable that start with '@' character.  See wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: values have been substituted already in string.xml
and if there is an issues with the '@' character so why its appearing error in view elements like in textView starting tag.

Comment: If you can do a "Rebuild Project" without errors, try:
"File>Invalidate Caches/Restart>Invalidate and Restart".
If that does not work and you can't "Rebuild Project" successfully, Instead of Importing the project do a "Open an existing Android Studio Project"
GL

Comment: Done with that but still having issues.
and when I sync my project with gradle file so these errors occurs.

ERROR: Failed to open zip file.
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue a while ago.

To solve this issue, delete following directory from your machine:
`C:\Users\your-username\.gradle\`

After this, open your project, invalidate cache and restart android studio and then sync your project with gradle files.